# Does ADFS expose a webservice that I can call?

Tags: authentication, adfs

I got ADFS to work with IdentityServer by Dominick Baier.  However I was wondering if I could use ADFS to authenticate against other Active Directories.

So for example:  Company 1 Hosts ADFS1 - I want this ADFS to authenticate a person against another Active Directory domain.  Can the FormsLogin page of ADFS1 be modified to talk to (authenticate a user against) another instance of ADFS that is setup as a ClaimsProvider in ADFS1?

Hope this makes sense. If not please let me know and I will explain.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand but:

Each instance of ADFS can authenticate against a single instance of AD. If you have two AD into two domains, install an instance of ADFS in each domain and federate them. The user (via Home Realm Discovery) will be asked which AD instance they wish to authenticate against.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  However the requirement is the client does not see the home realm discovery page at all.  They see the one formslogin.aspx page in ADFS1.  Currently I have that talking to thinktecture's identityserver using [link](http://garymcallisteronline.blogspot.com/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-4-adfs-20-and-3rd-party-sts.html).  Once the user enters the credentials in the formslogin page of ADFS1 it has to communicate with the corresponding ADFS the client is located in (which we will know) and authenticate them.

Comment: Do you want the user to choose or do certain groups only go to one or the other? If the latter, use the whr parameter.

Comment: sorry not sure how that will solve my problem. can you please explain?